# Data from sharedpreferences incorrect when validated on login.class

Tags: java, android, validation, authentication, android-sharedpreferences

### Login.class

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText Lname, Password;
    TextView Regit;
    Button Login, Cancel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        Lname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLname);
        Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
        Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        Cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        Regit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRegit);

        Regit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Registration.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Lname.setText("");
                Password.setText("");
            }
        });

        Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
           load();
            }
        });
    }

    public void run() {
        Intent x = new Intent(Login.this, MainPage.class);
        startActivity(x);
    }

       public void LoginSuccess() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully Logged in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        run();

    }


    public  void load(){


        final SharedPreferences pref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

        String value=(pref.getString("Name", Lname.getText().toString()));
        String value2=(pref.getString("Password", Password.getText().toString()));


        if (value.equals(Lname) & value2.equals(Password)){
            LoginSuccess();
        } else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Last Name or Password Incorrect or Does not Exist!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

---

### Registration.class

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Registration extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText Lname, Fname, Mname, BDate, Email, Password;
    String Lnamee, Fnamee, Mnamee, Bdatee, Emails, Passwords;
    TextView Login;
    Button Register, Cancel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

        Lname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtFamilyName);
        Fname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtFirstName);
        Mname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMiddleName);
        BDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtBDay);
        Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEMail);
        Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
        Register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        Cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        Login = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLogin);




        Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Registration.this, Login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Lname.setText("");
                Fname.setText("");
                Mname.setText("");
                BDate.setText("");
                Email.setText("");
                Password.setText("");
            }
        });

        Register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                register();
            }
        });
    }

    public void register() {
        initialize();
        if (!validate()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sign-up has Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            onSignUpSuccess();
        }
    }

    public void onSignUpSuccess() {
        save();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully Registered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Registration.this, Login.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
    public boolean validate() {
        boolean valid = true;
        if (Lnamee.isEmpty() || Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]*+").matcher(Lnamee).matches()) {
            Lname.setError("Enter letters only!");

            valid = false;
        }

        if (Mnamee.isEmpty() || Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]*+ ").matcher(Mnamee).matches()) {
           Mname.setError("Enter letters only!");
            valid = false;
        }

        if (Fnamee.isEmpty() || Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]*+").matcher(Fnamee).matches()) {
           Fname.setError("Enter letters only!");
            valid = false;
        }

       if (Emails.isEmpty() || Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]" + "\\@" + "[a-zA-Z]" + "\\." +  "[a-zA-Z]").matcher(Emails).matches()){
            Email.setError("Enter valid e-mail address!");
            valid = false;
        }

        if (Passwords.isEmpty() || Passwords.length() < 8){
           Password.setError("Password must be 8 characters!");
            valid = false;
        }
        return valid;


    }

    public void initialize(){
        Lnamee = Lname.getText().toString().trim();
        Mnamee = Mname.getText().toString().trim();
        Fnamee = Fname.getText().toString().trim();
        Emails = Email.getText().toString().trim();
        Passwords = Password.getText().toString().trim();
    }

    public void save() {
        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

        String LastNameReg = Lname.getText().toString();
        String PWReg = Password.getText().toString();

        editor.putString("Name", LastNameReg);
        editor.putString("Password", PWReg);
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

The expected behavior of the program would be, from the registration: when the user enters the Family Name or Last Name(txtFamilyName) & Password(txtPassword) it will be stored in sharedpreferences, and it will be use as a data to be entered for user to login(Login.class) and enter MainPage().

During registration(Registration.class), when I entered my Family or Last Name & Password, and use it on the Login.class, it does not enter to MainPage even though the required fields are correct.

Comment: Do you get any messages of any kind - crash errors or self made messages (such as your toasts)

Comment: After I entered the required fields, my toast pops up:  Toast.makeText(this, "Last Name or Password Incorrect or Does not Exist!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It occurs to me that you are comparing the value of an `EditView` object with the actual username / password strings. You also don't want to be using the Lname and Password values as "default" values. In this case, if there is no username / password saved it will always identify as logged in.

The changes made below should suffice.

```
public void load() {
    final SharedPreferences pref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

    String value=(pref.getString("Name", ""));
    String value2=(pref.getString("Password", ""));

    if (value.equals(Lname.getText().toString()) & value2.equals(Password.getText().toString())){
        LoginSuccess();
    } else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Last Name or Password Incorrect or Does not Exist!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Good! Make sure to mark it as answering your question with a tick!